# parse google document for text and copy result to sheet

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, text-parsing

I wish to parse a series of documents in a Google Drive folder using regular expressions.

The documents contain equipment model and serial numbers. I wish to then copy the results to a google sheet row by row. I have managed a similar task with emails successfully but to no avail with google docs.

Can anyone offer some guidance. I have tested the regular expressions in the 'find and replace' menu in google docs and they work fine. The following is simply an attempt to see if I can capture some data and write it to a cell in the active sheet.

```
function write() {
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var doc = 
DocumentApp.openById('1ZNqJjSJo1wkD3eaCRTY64g98hYEY77D4MDU6XpvA4MI');
var body = doc.getBody();
var text = body.findText('(\W|^)GSS\d{2}H(\W|$)')
  ss.getRange(1,1).setValue(text);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to retrieve all values matched by `(\W|^)GSS\d{2}H(\W|$)` in the document, and put the result to spreadsheet with row by row. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points :

- Retrieve text from document.
- Retrieve all matched values using the regex.

  - For this situation, I used [RegExp#exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).
- Put the result to spreadsheet.

#### Modified script :

```
function write() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1ZNqJjSJo1wkD3eaCRTY64g98hYEY77D4MDU6XpvA4MI');
  var body = doc.getBody();

  // Modified script
  var text = doc.getBody().getText();
  var result = [];
  var r = /(\W|^)GSS\d{2}H(\W|$)/g;
  while ((res = r.exec(text)) !== null) { // or while (res = r.exec(text)) {
    result.push([res[0]]);
  }
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow() + 1, 1, result.length, 1).setValues(result);
}
```

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry. At that time, could you please provide the sample input and output you need? I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: This works very nicely thank you, I understand the declaration of the array to hold the parsed values, but I will need to study the syntax of the "while' statement to understand how it is working. ( I can see WHAT it is doing). I wish to copy the filename of the document being parsed to the first sheet column and two separate parsed values for model and serial number to the second and third columns. If you are happy to offer more assistance let me know what you need. I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: @Phillip Armstrong  Thank you for replying. About ``I wish to copy the filename of the document being parsed to the first sheet column and two separate parsed values for model and serial number to the second and third columns.``, could you please provide the sample output? I would like to support about it.

Comment: Im not sure if that was an accept or vote check i highlighted Tanaike

Comment: @Phillip Armstrong Thank you for your concern. I think that I can support about the output you want. Can you provide the sample output you want?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/155_vgZ_jQaYXLrCQXPFqunBtxV0GU32Jvja7HlGGg6g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Phillip Armstrong 1. You can retrieve the filename of document by ``doc.getName()``. 2. Although I have no information about the model and serial number, you can retrieve them by my modified script. Please use the regex for the serial number when it retrieves them. 3. Please create the result array like ``[[filename, model, serial number]]``, and put them using ``setValues()``.

Comment: @Phillip Armstrong References are [getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getName()) and [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues). If you need the detail information of them, please check them.

Comment: Tanaike, Sorry, just thinking through your advice, I understand the getName() and setValues(). Do I declare a second variable for the serial number regex  and and another statement for it to the While loop? I think maybe back to school for Me!

Comment: @Phillip Armstrong Yes. You can retrieve the values of serial number using the while loop like the modified script. As a method, you can create the result array after retrieved all values. For example, if several mode and serial numbers are included in a document and the number of model and serial numbers are the same, the result can be retrieved as follows. ``var result = []; for (var i=0;i<model.length;i++) result.push([fileName, model[i], serialNumber[i]]);`` ``model`` and ``serialNumber`` are one dimensional array. I'm sorry that I have only a little information about your situation.